# Can we represent any linear recursion as A(alpha)^n + B(beta)^n?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursion, fibonacci-numbers

I was trying to solve some linear recursion problems and wonder if this relation holds true for all linear recursions or is it just limited to a few ? I know the Fibonacci follows this rule.

Comment: Great first question! You might want to learn about linear recurrences' solutions in general.

Comment: Good question. I suggest studying the Wikipedia article [Recurrenc relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation).

Comment: That is the case for homogeneous linear recurrence relations with constant coefficients, ie, recurrence of the form $c_na_n+c_{n-1}a_{n-1}+\ldots+c_{n-k}a_{n-k}=0$; Fibonacci (Lucas) numbers' recurrence is of this form. But it is not the case for any linear recurrence relation, eg. $a_n=a_{n-1}+1;~a_0=0$

Comment: If the recurrence is of the form $x_{n+1}=cx_n+dx_{n-1}$ we can write it this way, except when $c^2=-4d.$ Then it is of the form $$x_n=(A+Bn)\left(\frac c2\right)^n.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, definitely solved it !